# How do I extract text from SVN commit log to insert in a Jenkins email?

Tags: svn, jenkins, email-ext

We are using Jenkins over a Subversion repository.  After the build, Jenkins sends a notification email with email-ext.  We have Bugzilla/Subversion integration: if a comment contains "bug 1234", then Bugzilla's ticket 1234 is updated.

I want Jenkin's notification email subject to contain the bug number associated with the Subversion commit.  How can I do that?

I would like the subject of the email to be something like: Jenkins - build #44 - bug 1234

For bonus points: it would be awesome if after pulling the number, the solution could also make a query to the Bugzilla server and get the bug's summary.  Then the summary could be inserted in the email subject.

Then the subject could be: Jenkins - build 44 - Name field is disabled on update

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line to get build number, and svn comment in email-ext plugin default content. 
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, changesFormat=" %m
"}